# Integrating formula with x values from array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I want to integrate a formula for all x values that are in an array.
How do I use the array for the values of x?

And do I need to integrate the formula by hand before that?
The original formula that needs to be integrated would be (a*(4-x))-b

It is also important to note, that the array does contain multiple identical values

Comment: Do you mind posting an example array, please? It's ahrd to understand what you're asking without one.

Comment: Of course: [0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]

Comment: If necessary (to get a better outcome) the array could be changed to have more (or only) unique values as well

Comment: So are you trying to integrate within the range [0,4]? Because integration doesn't just happen at integer values; it happens within a range, in which case any values within the range are unimportant.

Comment: Exactly, 4 will be the max value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to integerate in the range `[0, 4]`, here's something you can do that does not require finding the integral by hand:

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import scipy.special as special

# Defining the function you're integrating by
def this_funct(x, a, b):
    return (a*(4-x)) - b

# Range you are integrating along
bottom_of_range = 0
top_of_range = 4

# Change a and b to be whatever you want
a = 3
b = 4

# Result contains the integral of this_funct in the range (bottom_of_range, top_of_range).
result = integrate.quad(lambda x: this_funct(x, a, b), bottom_of_range, top_of_range)[0]
```

You can change `bottom_of_range`, `top_of_range`, `a` and `b` as needed.